# Add new item on listview from fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-listview

i have an Alarm app which contain 3 tabs (3 Fragments) , First one is "Edit" , And second one is "Alarm" which display a list-view of all alarms , Finally last tab is "Add Alarm" i have time-picker and button , i want when i pick a time and click on add button take that values to tab "alarm" and add it to list-view.

My code doesn't work.

This is my code :

**MainActivity.java**

```
 public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        Intent intent = getIntent();
        String my_alarm_hour = intent.getStringExtra("HOUR");
        String my_alarm_subject = intent.getStringExtra("SUBJECT");
        String my_alarm_format = intent.getStringExtra("FORMAT");

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        SectionsPagerAdapter sectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(this, getSupportFragmentManager() , my_alarm_hour);
        ViewPager viewPager = findViewById(R.id.view_pager);
        viewPager.setAdapter(sectionsPagerAdapter);
        viewPager.setCurrentItem(1);
        TabLayout tabs = findViewById(R.id.tabs);
        tabs.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
     }
   }
```

And here **Add Alarm.java**

```
public class Add extends Fragment {


  public Add() {
    // Required empty public constructor
  }

private TimePicker timePicker ;
private TextView tv ;
private Button add ;
private EditText label;
private String format = "";
public String subject = "";
static  final String ADD_TIME_ALARM = "add_alarm";


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_add, container, false);

    tv = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.textView5);
    timePicker = (TimePicker) v.findViewById(R.id.datePicker1);

    label = (EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.subject) ;
    add = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.addAlarm);

    add.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            addNewAlarm();
        }
    });

    return v;
}

public void addNewAlarm()
{
    subject = label.getText().toString();
    int hour = timePicker.getHour();
    //int minute = timePicker.getCurrentMinute();
    if (hour == 0) {
        hour += 12;
        format = "AM";
    } else if (hour == 12) {
        format = "PM";
    } else if (hour > 12) {
        hour -= 12;
        format = "PM";
    } else {
        format = "AM";
    }

    Times time = new Times(String.valueOf(hour) , format , "test" , subject  );

    Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity().getBaseContext(), MainActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra("test23" , time);
    getActivity().setResult(MainActivity.RESULT_OK, intent);
}
}
```

**Alarm.java**
Which contain ListView of alarms .

```
public class Alarm extends Fragment {

public ArrayList<Times> names = new ArrayList<>();

public Alarm() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}
final int REQ_CODE_ADD = 1;
ListView list;
Button goAddAlarm ;
String format  = "";
String subject = "";
myAdapter adapter;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_alarm, container, false);;
    list = v.findViewById(R.id.listview);

    goAddAlarm =  v.findViewById(R.id.goAddAlarm);
    goAddAlarm.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity().getBaseContext() , Add.class);
            startActivityForResult(intent,REQ_CODE_ADD);
        }
    });
   //       names.add(new Times( "07:09" , "AM" , "Wed , Mon" , "-Home Time"));

     adapter = new myAdapter(getContext(), R.layout.custom_list_alarm , names);
     list.setAdapter(adapter);

    return v;
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if( requestCode == REQ_CODE_ADD && requestCode == MainActivity.RESULT_OK)
    {
        Times alarm = (Times) data.getSerializableExtra("test23");
        adapter.addAlarm(alarm);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
  }
}
```

**And here is adapter for 3 fragment PagerAdapter**

```
public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

@StringRes
private static final int[] TAB_TITLES = new int[]{R.string.tab_text_1, R.string.tab_text_2 , R.string.tab_text_3};
private final Context mContext;
private String time;

public SectionsPagerAdapter(Context context, FragmentManager fm , String time ) {
    super(fm);
    mContext = context;
    this.time = time;
}

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    // getItem is called to instantiate the fragment for the given page.
    // Return a PlaceholderFragment (defined as a static inner class below).
    Fragment fragment = new Fragment();
    switch (position)
    {
        case 0:
            fragment = new Edit();
            break;
        case 1:
            fragment = new Alarm();
            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
            bundle.putString("hour1", time);
            fragment.setArguments(bundle);

            break;
        case 2:
            fragment = new Add();
            break;
    }
    return fragment;
}

@Nullable
@Override
public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
    return mContext.getResources().getString(TAB_TITLES[position]);
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    // Show 2 total pages.
    return 3;
}
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! What exactly does not work? What do you see on the screen and what do you want to see instead?

Comment: thank you , it don't add a new item on the listView , Maybe my whole code is wrong , so i am asking you do you have and guide that tech me how to create 2 fragment and 1 of them have a listview and another one have a button to add item on that list view(in fragment 1) , and thank you soo much for your helping